# How do I fix this unmet dependencies?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dependencies

doing some updates today and ran in to this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libhashkit-dev : Depends: libhashkit2 (= 1.0.18-4.2ubuntu2) but 1.1.3-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is installed
 libmemcached-dev : Depends: libhashkit-dev (= 1.1.3-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but 1.0.18-4.2ubuntu2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

how do I correct it so I can finish my updates?

Comment: Look at your output carefully: `libhashkit2 1.0.18-4.2ubuntu2` is standard for Ubuntu 18.04, which we no longer provide support for. It's too old. `libhashkit2 1.1.3-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1` is from some non-Ubuntu source. The solution is to 1) Migrate your data to a newer, supported release of Ubuntu, and 2) Avoid using non-Ubuntu sources.